# Morse Encoder Whitespace Removal

Tags: java, removing-whitespace, morse-code

I made good prgress with my Morse Code Translator with the help from you but there still is a problem with whitespaces, if the text has unknown char in it.

This is the method I use for translate a single char to morse code while using hashmaps (no problems with that!)

```
public String getMorseCode(char c) {
    char cUpper = Character.toUpperCase(c);
    if (charMap.containsKey(cUpper)) {
        return charMap.get(cUpper);
    } else {
        final String emptyString = "";
        return emptyString;
    }
}
```

Using this method I translate the text to morse code using the encoding method:

```
public String encode(String text) {
    StringBuilder sb1 = new StringBuilder();
    int i = 0;
    while (i < text.length()) {
        char c = text.charAt(i);
        if (c == ' ') {
            sb1.append("/");
            i++;
        } else {
            i = i + 1;
            sb1.append(getMorseCode(c));
        }
        sb1.append("*");
    }
    return sb1.toString().trim();
}
```

Whitespaces before and after the sentence are removed via .trim(). In morsecode between words are 3 whitespaces, between chars 1 whitespace. If the text has a unknown char in it, there should be an empty string ("") without a whitespace after it. I change the whitespace in the method to / and * to see how things change, but got still the same problem.

I simply don't know how to change my code to make this happen! 
Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You need to check whether you returned an empty string or not. Only if it's not empty, you add the whitespace.

```
while (i < text.length()) {
    char c = text.charAt(i);
    i++;
    if (c == ' ') {
        sb1.append("/");
    } else {
        String code = getMorseCode(c);
        if ( ! code.equals("") ) {
           sb1.append(code);
           sb1.append('*');
        }
    }
}
```

BTW, a `for` loop might be more appropriate than a `while` here since you are processing all the characters in sequence..